# Android Joda-Time with Kotlin

Tags: android, datetime, kotlin, jodatime

I am trying to create a function to check a given string time *HH:mm* is in range of another comparing to now.

Example: if the current hour is between 12:35 and 15:00 return true

*But I always got **false** even if the current time is in range..*

```
fun isTimeInRange(before: String, after: String): Boolean {
    val now = DateTime.now()
    val format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm")
    return now >= DateTime.parse(before, format) && now <= DateTime.parse(after, format)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set before/after date to today's date. try this:

```
fun isTimeInRange(start: String, end: String): Boolean {
    val now = DateTime.now()
    val format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm")
    val startTime: LocalTime = format.parseLocalTime(start)
    val endTime: LocalTime = format.parseLocalTime(end)
    val timeZone = DateTimeZone.getDefault()
    val today: LocalDate = LocalDate.now(timeZone)
    val startMoment: DateTime = today.toLocalDateTime(startTime).toDateTime(timeZone)
    val endMoment: DateTime = today.toLocalDateTime(endTime).toDateTime(timeZone)
    return now.isAfter(startMoment) && now.isBefore(endMoment)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do:

```
fun isTimeInRange(before: String, after: String): Boolean {
    val now = DateTime.now()
    val format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm")
    return now.isAfter(DateTime.parse(before, format)) && now.isBefore(DateTime.parse(after, format))
}
```

Or use [intervals](https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-use-the-interval-class-of-joda-time/).

Comment: Still got false even when I'm in range `utilityHelper.isTimeInRange("17:00", "21:30")`. that strange...

Comment: Try using intervals. Other thing that could be the problem is you're using DateTime without a timezone.

Comment: Intervals is using a complete date pattern.. I need only the hour pattern HH:mm , where could I add a timeZone?

Comment: If you're using gradle version of 6.0 or greater you could try using the Java 8 DateTime library.  https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table.  In this way, you could use LocalDateTime. You didn't say what timezone you are in now.  I'm in MST, so it would definitely return false for me now (it is morning here)

Comment: unfortunately i need a version under 6 for this project, but I'm sure joda time has a easy solution, maybe I need to put in parameter the timezone as you said.. the question is where? hmm..   (I need only  the timezone for  France  it's not an international app for now  )

Comment: by the way DateTime.now() is already in my local timeZone.. so I don't think the problem is coming from there..

Comment: You could use the ThreeTen backport which has LocalDateTime.